# Keras: single input layer for repeated multi inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, keras, layer

So, I got this multi-input model with 6 identical inputs of same shape. Right now If I have to use this model, I have to multiply my input data with total numbers of input layer, i.e. 6. I was wondering if I can add another layer on top of this and can pass single input that will connect with all these 6 inputs. I'm not sure how to accomplish this! Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: You mean you want to concatenate them?

Comment: No,, I don't think he wants to concatenate because the inputs are identical. Can you please elaborate the problem? What kind of operation do you want to do with this?

Comment: Why can't you just reuse a single input layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was something like this: I have a *"BASE"* multi-input model, where all inputs are identical, as this *"BASE"* model was just a combination of multiple models which happens to share identical type input! Now, when using this *"BASE"* model for classification, I had to provide **[input_data x "total_inputs"]** for each input layer, which is something I don't wanted to do, say when classifying millions of sentences!

So, the ideal solution was to just have a single input which is connected with all *"BASE"* model inputs!!

Alrighty, so here is how it's done:

1. Create a new `top_model` which will take single input and generate multiple identical outputs. This can be done with `Lambda` layer.

   ```
   single_input = layers.Input(input_shape)
   multi_output = layers.Lambda(lambda x: [x] * total_numbers_of_base_inputs)(single_input)
   top_model = Model(inputs=single_input, outputs=multi_output)
   ```
2. Use the `top_model` input and your `multi_input_base_model` like below to create new **single_input** model.

   ```
   new_model = Model(inputs=top_model.input, outputs=multi_input_base_model(top_model.output))
   ```